# What are the possible problems when updating a live ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I update a live ASP.NET application frequently. I have a load balancing set up, so I update each server while no one is on it.

However, there are still problems from time to time, commonly with people loading a page on the old version and then submitting it on the new version and then the viewstate cannot be decoded.

That's the type of generic problem I'm looking for a list of.

I am looking for a **complete** list of generic problems that can occur after an update, so I can become aware of when and where my update will cause problems for people using the system at the same time.

Of course problems can occur if there are errors etc. in the update or the code, but I'm obviously not talking about that.

Comment: [Happy searching](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Post your results here when you're done.

Comment: Uwe, the link you provided, is this a subtle comment on the phrasing of my question? Please help me if you have critique or advice on how to improve it.

Comment: Having re-read the question, I think I guessed your point, as it was phrased way to broad. I edited it now and hope it will be clearer for the next people coming to read it.

Comment: I found the original question just as clear(if not more) than after the edit ...

Comment: Niels, in your original question you mention that sessions are not a problem, why not? i'd expect every user to lose his session and be redirected to the login page thus having no chance on an error.

Comment: Kristof, I use ASP.NET State Server and it works perfectly. We never have any problems with that. But I guess for the list to be complete for other people finding the question, we should include possible session problems, that's why I removed it.

Comment: I actually discovered that updating .NET version DOES cause users to lose their session, despite the use of ASP.NET State Server (on a different server)